# How to understand Using :: (Scope resolution operator) to access a in-class class (nested class) or typedef

Tags: c++, class, scope, typedef

I'm trying to understand Scope resolution operator `::`
I know I can only access static class member via Scope resolution operator. 
But I can use it to access typedef or a nested class thing like this:

```cpp
class test{
    public:
    class testinner{
        public:
        int _val;
        testinner(){}
        testinner(int x):_val(x){}
    };
    test(){}
    typedef int testdef;


    int s;
};

int main()
{
    test::testinner tt1 = test::testinner(5); //OK LINE(1)
    test::testinner tt2; //OK LINE(2)
    test::testdef tt3 = 5; //OK LINE(3)
    test::s = 5; //non static member ERROR LINE(4)

    return 0;
}
```

I can instantiate an in-class type object via `::` such as `line 1` and `line 2`
I can use typedef to instantiate an object such as `line 3`
I can't access non-static members via `::` such as `line 4`

Is that mean an in-class class and typedef is a static member in a class?
I know namespace is quite equal to class name but I'm still really getting confused about it.

By the way, for the typedef part, can I simply think `tt3` is `int` type rather than `test::testdef` type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't access non-static members via `::` such as `line 4`

False. The problem is that you cannot access non-static members without an object. If you have an object, you can use a qualified name (with `::`).

```cpp
int main()
{
    test t;
    t.test::s = 5;
    //^^^^^^
}
```

> Is that mean an in-class class and typedef is a static member in a class?

It depends what you mean by "static member". They do not require an object of the class, but at the same time they do not require the `static` keyword. (My understanding is that in the official terminology, nested types and typedefs are not considered "members", so in that respect they are not static members. However, I think that might be side-stepping the intended question.)

> By the way, for the typedef part, can I simply think `tt3` is `int` type rather than `test::testdef` type?

Up to you. A `typedef` creates an alias, so `int` and `test::testdef` are two names for the same thing. If you prefer thinking in terms of `int`, do that. If you prefer thinking in terms of `test::testdef`, do that. The type doesn't mind which name you use.

(The same would hold if the `typedef` was outside a class definition. You are making the situation less clear for yourself by thinking that the class makes a difference in this case. A `typedef` defines an alias for a type.)